# WPF DataTemplate table only show one row

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a table with xaml design. However the program only shows one row, but I have many more rows.

[image]

**xaml design:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Windows_Backup_Folders_to_External_Disks_Csharp.BackupOverview"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Windows_Backup_Folders_to_External_Disks_Csharp"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="670" d:DesignWidth="1050">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="Backup Overview" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <Label x:Name="labelBackupOverviewAbout" Content="Here you will see all backups that have been handled by the program." HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.547,-1.039" FontSize="16"/>
        <Label x:Name="labelBackupOverviewAboutB" Content="You can search by directory name below." HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,65,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.547,-1.039" FontSize="16"/>

        <ContentControl Content="{Binding backupOverviewModel}" x:Name="contentControlBackupOverview" Margin="10,141,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Border Background="#e2e2e2" Padding="4,4,4,4" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                                <TextBlock Text="DateTime" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Background="#e2e2e2" Padding="4,4,4,4" BorderThickness="0,1" BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                                <TextBlock Text="Source" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Background="#e2e2e2" Padding="4,4,4,4" BorderThickness="0,1" BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                                <TextBlock Text="RootDirectory" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Background="#e2e2e2" Padding="4,4,4,4" BorderThickness="0,1" BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                                <TextBlock Text="SourceDirectoryName" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Background="#e2e2e2" Padding="4,4,4,4" BorderThickness="0,1" BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                                <TextBlock Text="SourcePath" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Background="#e2e2e2" Padding="4,4,4,4" BorderThickness="0,1" BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                                <TextBlock Text="SourceFile" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Background="#e2e2e2" Padding="4,4,4,4" BorderThickness="0,1" BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                                <TextBlock Text="TargetLetter" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Background="#e2e2e2" Padding="4,4,4,4" BorderThickness="0,1,1,1" BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                                <TextBlock Text="TargetDiskName" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            </Border>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Border Background="#f8f8f8" Padding="4,4,4,4" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding dateTime}" FontSize="16"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Background="#f8f8f8" Padding="4,4,4,4" BorderThickness="0,1" BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding source}" FontSize="16"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Background="#f8f8f8" Padding="4,4,4,4" BorderThickness="0,1" BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding rootDirectory}" FontSize="16"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Background="#f8f8f8" Padding="4,4,4,4" BorderThickness="0,1" BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding sourceDirectoryName}" FontSize="16"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Background="#f8f8f8" Padding="4,4,4,4" BorderThickness="0,1" BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding sourcePath}" FontSize="16"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Background="#f8f8f8" Padding="4,4,4,4" BorderThickness="0,1" BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding sourceFile}" FontSize="16"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Background="#f8f8f8" Padding="4,4,4,4" BorderThickness="0,1" BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding targetLetter}" FontSize="16"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Background="#f8f8f8" Padding="4,4,4,4" BorderThickness="0,1,1,1" BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding targetDiskName}" FontSize="16"/>
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>


        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**xaml.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Windows_Backup_Folders_to_External_Disks_Csharp.model;

namespace Windows_Backup_Folders_to_External_Disks_Csharp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for BackupOverview.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class BackupOverview : UserControl
    {
        public BackupOverview()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            updateDataTable();
        }

        private void updateDataTable()
        {
            // Read
            string userPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
            string folderPath = userPath + "\\" + "WindowsBackupFoldersToExternalDisk" + "\\" + "backupOverview";
            if (Directory.Exists(folderPath))
            {

                // Process the list of files found in the directory.
                string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);
                foreach (string directoriesFile in fileEntries)
                {
                    // Read file "directoriesFiles"
                    string readDirectoryFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(directoriesFile);
                    string[] separatorLineShift = new string[] { "\n" };
                    string[] linesArray = readDirectoryFile.Split(separatorLineShift, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    foreach (string line in linesArray)
                    {

                        if (!(line.Equals("")))
                        {
                            // Design:  dateTime + "|" + source + "|" + rootDirectory + "|" + sourceDirectoryName + "|" + sourcePath + "|" + sourceFile + "|" + targetLetter + "|" + targetDiskName
                            // Example: 28 juli 2019 21:29:10|C:\SourceA|C:\SourceA\7875000|7875000|C:\SourceA\7875000\Raw images|img003.txt|D:\|-

                            string[] separatorPipe = new string[] { "|" };
                            string[] lineArray = line.Split(separatorPipe, StringSplitOptions.None);

                            String dateTime             = lineArray[0];
                            String source               = lineArray[1];
                            String rootDirectory        = lineArray[2];
                            String sourceDirectoryName  = lineArray[3];
                            String sourcePath           = lineArray[4];
                            String sourceFile           = lineArray[5];
                            String targetLetter         = lineArray[6];
                            String targetDiskName       = lineArray[7];

                            BackupOverviewModel backupOverviewModel = new BackupOverviewModel(dateTime, source, rootDirectory, sourceDirectoryName, sourcePath, sourceFile, targetLetter, targetDiskName);
                            contentControlBackupOverview.Content = backupOverviewModel;


                        } // lines not empty
                    } // foreach lines

                } // foreach directories-files


            } // directory exists
        } // updateDataTable
    } // class
}
```

**BackupOverviewModel**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Windows_Backup_Folders_to_External_Disks_Csharp.model
{

    class BackupOverviewModel
    {
        // jobDateTime + "|" + jobSource + "|" + jobRootDirectory + "|" + jobSourceDirectoryName + "|" + jobSourcePath
        // + "|" + jobSourceFile + "|" + targetLetter + "|" + targetDiskName

        public String dateTime { get; set; }
        public String source { get; set; }
        public String rootDirectory { get; set; }
        public String sourceDirectoryName { get; set; }
        public String sourcePath { get; set; }
        public String sourceFile { get; set; }
        public String targetLetter { get; set; }
        public String targetDiskName { get; set; }

        public BackupOverviewModel(String dateTime, String source, String rootDirectory, String sourceDirectoryName, String sourcePath, String sourceFile, String targetLetter, String targetDiskName)
        {
            this.dateTime = dateTime;
            this.source = source;
            this.rootDirectory = rootDirectory;
            this.sourceDirectoryName = sourceDirectoryName;
            this.sourcePath = sourcePath;
            this.sourceFile = sourceFile;
            this.targetLetter = targetLetter;
            this.targetDiskName = targetDiskName;
        }

    }
}
```

The program reads text files for the backup overview table stored in "C:\Users\user\WindowsBackupFoldersToExternalDisk\backupOverview". I checked the code and it receives many lines, so there should be a lot of rows printed in my program.

Comment: I do not see any property where you expose a collection, so I asume you only expose a single instance - if that much? I wrote a introduction into the MVVM pattern a few years ago, but it should still be helpfull: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1a8bf14-4acd-4d77-9df8-bdb95b02dbe2/lets-talk-about-mvvm?forum=wpf

Comment: I dont see any table or gridview in your XAML.

Answer (score 2):

In your view (inside your `foreach` loop) you are overwriting the `ContentControl.Content` property on each iteration. `ContentControl` can only host a *single* element, in your case a single line.

What you need is an `ItemsControl` like a `ListView` which can display a *set*  of items (or rows). You can use your exact `DataTemplate` to define the `ListView.ItemTeplate`:

**BackupOverview.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="BackupOverview">
  <UserControl.DataContext>
    <BackupOverviewViewModel />
  </UserControl.DataContext>

  <Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="Backup Overview"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="10,10,0,0"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               FontSize="20"
               FontWeight="Bold" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="labelBackupOverviewAbout"
               Text="Here you will see all backups that have been handled by the program."
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="10,47,0,0"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               RenderTransformOrigin="-0.547,-1.039"
               FontSize="16" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="labelBackupOverviewAboutB"
               Text="You can search by directory name below."
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="10,65,0,0"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               RenderTransformOrigin="-0.547,-1.039"
               FontSize="16" />

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TableRows}"
              x:Name="BackupOverviewTable"
              Margin="10,141,0,0"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left">

      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="TableRowDataModel">
          <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Border Background="#e2e2e2"
                      Padding="4,4,4,4"
                      BorderThickness="1,1,0,1"
                      BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                <TextBlock Text="DateTime"
                           FontSize="16"
                           FontWeight="Bold" />
              </Border>
              <Border Background="#e2e2e2"
                      Padding="4,4,4,4"
                      BorderThickness="0,1"
                      BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                <TextBlock Text="Source"
                           FontSize="16"
                           FontWeight="Bold" />
              </Border>
              <Border Background="#e2e2e2"
                      Padding="4,4,4,4"
                      BorderThickness="0,1"
                      BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                <TextBlock Text="RootDirectory"
                           FontSize="16"
                           FontWeight="Bold" />
              </Border>
              <Border Background="#e2e2e2"
                      Padding="4,4,4,4"
                      BorderThickness="0,1"
                      BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                <TextBlock Text="SourceDirectoryName"
                           FontSize="16"
                           FontWeight="Bold" />
              </Border>
              <Border Background="#e2e2e2"
                      Padding="4,4,4,4"
                      BorderThickness="0,1"
                      BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                <TextBlock Text="SourcePath"
                           FontSize="16"
                           FontWeight="Bold" />
              </Border>
              <Border Background="#e2e2e2"
                      Padding="4,4,4,4"
                      BorderThickness="0,1"
                      BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                <TextBlock Text="SourceFile"
                           FontSize="16"
                           FontWeight="Bold" />
              </Border>
              <Border Background="#e2e2e2"
                      Padding="4,4,4,4"
                      BorderThickness="0,1"
                      BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                <TextBlock Text="TargetLetter"
                           FontSize="16"
                           FontWeight="Bold" />
              </Border>
              <Border Background="#e2e2e2"
                      Padding="4,4,4,4"
                      BorderThickness="0,1,1,1"
                      BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                <TextBlock Text="TargetDiskName"
                           FontSize="16"
                           FontWeight="Bold" />
              </Border>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Border Background="#f8f8f8"
                      Padding="4,4,4,4"
                      BorderThickness="1,1,0,1"
                      BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding dateTime}"
                           FontSize="16" />
              </Border>
              <Border Background="#f8f8f8"
                      Padding="4,4,4,4"
                      BorderThickness="0,1"
                      BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding source}"
                           FontSize="16" />
              </Border>
              <Border Background="#f8f8f8"
                      Padding="4,4,4,4"
                      BorderThickness="0,1"
                      BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding rootDirectory}"
                           FontSize="16" />
              </Border>
              <Border Background="#f8f8f8"
                      Padding="4,4,4,4"
                      BorderThickness="0,1"
                      BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding sourceDirectoryName}"
                           FontSize="16" />
              </Border>
              <Border Background="#f8f8f8"
                      Padding="4,4,4,4"
                      BorderThickness="0,1"
                      BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding sourcePath}"
                           FontSize="16" />
              </Border>
              <Border Background="#f8f8f8"
                      Padding="4,4,4,4"
                      BorderThickness="0,1"
                      BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding sourceFile}"
                           FontSize="16" />
              </Border>
              <Border Background="#f8f8f8"
                      Padding="4,4,4,4"
                      BorderThickness="0,1"
                      BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding targetLetter}"
                           FontSize="16" />
              </Border>
              <Border Background="#f8f8f8"
                      Padding="4,4,4,4"
                      BorderThickness="0,1,1,1"
                      BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding targetDiskName}"
                           FontSize="16" />
              </Border>
            </StackPanel>
          </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ContentTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I replaced all `Label` elements with `TextBlock` which have better performance (rendering). For simple text presentation (except in `FlowDocument` elements it is recommended to use a simple lightweight `TextBlock`. (Optimizing Performance: Text: [`FlowDocument`, `TextBlock`, and `Label` Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-text#flowdocument-textblock-and-label-controls))

**BackupOverviewViewModel.cs**

```
class BackupOverviewViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public BackupOverviewViewModel()
  {
    this.TableRows = new ObservableCollection<TableRowDataModel>();
    CreateTableRowData();
  }

  private void CreateTableRowData()
  {
    // Read
    string userPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
    string folderPath = userPath + @"\WindowsBackupFoldersToExternalDisk\backupOverview";

    if (Directory.Exists(folderPath))
    {
      // Immediately process each file found in the directory.
      IEnumerable<string> fileEntries = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath);
      foreach (string file in fileEntries)
      {
        // Retrieve line by line from file
        foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(directoriesFile)
        {
          if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
          {
            // Design:  dateTime + "|" + source + "|" + rootDirectory + "|" + sourceDirectoryName + "|" + sourcePath + "|" + sourceFile + "|" + targetLetter + "|" + targetDiskName
            // Example: 28 juli 2019 21:29:10|C:\SourceA|C:\SourceA\7875000|7875000|C:\SourceA\7875000\Raw images|img003.txt|D:\|-

            string[] lineArray = line.Split(new[] {'|'}, StringSplitOptions.None);

            String dateTime = lineArray[0];
            String source = lineArray[1];
            String rootDirectory = lineArray[2];
            String sourceDirectoryName = lineArray[3];
            String sourcePath = lineArray[4];
            String sourceFile = lineArray[5];
            String targetLetter = lineArray[6];
            String targetDiskName = lineArray[7];

            var tableRowDataModel = new TableRowDataModel(
              dateTime,
              source,
              rootDirectory,
              sourceDirectoryName,
              sourcePath,
              sourceFile,
              targetLetter,
              targetDiskName);

            this.TableRows.Add(tableRowModel);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public ObservableCollection<TableRowDataModel> TableRows { get; set; }

  #region INotifyPropertyChanged

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }

  #endregion
}
```

**TableRowModel.cs**

```
class TableRowDataModel
{
  public TableRowDataModel(String dateTime, String source, String rootDirectory, String sourceDirectoryName, String sourcePath, String sourceFile, String targetLetter, String targetDiskName)
  {
     this.DateTime = dateTime;
     this.Source = source;
     this.RootDirectory = rootDirectory;
     this.SourceDirectoryName = sourceDirectoryName;
     this.SourcePath = sourcePath;
     this.SourceFile = sourceFile;
     this.TargetLetter = targetLetter;
     this.TargetDiskName = targetDiskName;
  }

  public String DateTime { get; set; }
  public String Source { get; set; }
  public String RootDirectory { get; set; }
  public String SourceDirectoryName { get; set; }
  public String SourcePath { get; set; }
  public String SourceFile { get; set; }
  public String TargetLetter { get; set; }
  public String TargetDiskName { get; set; }
}
```

### Alternative Approach

Use a [`DataGrid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid?view=netframework-4.8#examples). This means far less code and better readability (the intend is also clear):

**BackupOverview.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="BackupOverview">
  <UserControl.DataContext>
    <BackupOverviewViewModel />
  </UserControl.DataContext>

  <Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TableRows}" />
  </Grid>
</UserCOntrol>
```

The column headers are named like the property names. To customize the column header you can add column definitions like this:

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TableRows}">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date Time"
                           Binding="{Binding DateTime}"
                           Width="100" />
     </DataGrid.Columns>
   </DataGrid>
```

### Remarks

I optimized the file reading some. `Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath);` reads the files of a folder deferred this significantly improves performance on larger directories opposed to `DirectoryGetFiles()`, which instantly reads *all*  files.

> The EnumerateFiles and GetFiles methods differ as follows: When you use EnumerateFiles, you can start enumerating the collection of names before the whole collection is returned; when you use GetFiles, you must wait for the whole array of names to be returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are working with many files and directories, EnumerateFiles can be more efficient.

The same applies to `File.ReadLines()` which also defers enumeration of the files (returns an `IEnumerable<string>` instead of a `string`). `File.ReadAllText()` reads all lines at once which can lead to bad performance on larger files:

> The ReadLines and ReadAllLines methods differ as follows: When you use ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before the whole collection is returned; when you use ReadAllLines, you must wait for the whole array of strings be returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are working with very large files, ReadLines can be more efficient.